# Why doesn't my button text show when on top of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have a QR Code Scanner view in which I have an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and a UIButton.

When this view displays, the text within the button does not show.  It should display the word 'Cancel'. If I touch the button, or swipe the button - but not tap it, the button text will show at that point.

Does anyone know how I can get the button text to display properly?

Here's what my view hierarchy looks like:

[image]

When I first enter the Scanner view, the buttons look like this:

[image]

There is no text. The text will show only after I touch the buttons:

[image]

One last thing, it seems this is an issue only is iOS 10...

Any suggestions welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to add an overlay view.

Main view containing video preview and overlay view.
Overlay view contains buttons.

For each button, you can use these events if you want to animate:

- TouchDown
- TouchUpInside
- TouchOutInside

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestions, but unfortunately, it did not work.  It seems as if the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer has the focus. If I touch the button - or any button I add to this view - they all behave the same. No text until they are touched.  Anyone know of a way to explicitly set focus on a UIButton?

Comment: And you layer is a sublayer of video preview view?

Comment: no, it is a sibling layer. if i make it a sublayer, the button does not show at all.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation of `AVCaptureSession` states, `startRunning()` call blocks the main thread so your UI is not drawn correctly.

> The startRunning() method is a blocking call which can take some time,
>   therefore you should perform session setup on a serial queue so that
>   the main queue isn't blocked (which keeps the UI responsive). See
>   AVCam-iOS: Using AVFoundation to Capture Images and Movies for an
>   implementation example.

If you check Apple's example (Swift 3 and Objective-C), you can easily set a new queue for those actions without blocking your main thread.

This is the example for Swift 2.3 if you need it.

```
// Swift 2.3

private let sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("session queue", nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dispatch_async(sessionQueue) { 
        self.configureSession()
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
        self.setupScreen()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use layer.insertSublayer(..., above: ...) or layer.insertSublayer(..., below: ...) to control your CALayers 
Here's the similar answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240520/how-to-bring-the-navigation-bar-on-top-of-the-camera-frame) or
 a bit more detailed instructions for Swift how to insert image on the top of video stream [manual](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/08/04/swift-put-overlay-on-top-of-avcapturevideopreviewlayer/#more-381)