# How to bring the navigation bar on top of the camera frame?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am creating a QR code scanner in my app. 
It includes the navigation bar, QRcode camera and a result box. Here is what I want to do.
[With navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODpuu.png)

But when I run in my phone, the navigation bar is behind the camera frame. 
[Without navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d6yt.jpg)

I have tried to insert a outlet of the navigation bar into my code and insert add `view.bringSubview(toFront: navigationbar)` but Xcode said it is not a `UIview`so I got the error. I am new to IOS development, any help will be appreciated.

Here is part of my code:

```
    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?
     @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
    // Added to support different barcodes
    let supportedBarCodes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {
            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

            // Initialize the captureSession object.
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
            // Set the input device on the capture session.
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

            // Detect all the supported bar code
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedBarCodes

            // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

            // Start video capture
            captureSession?.startRunning()

            // Move the message label to the top view
            view.bringSubview(toFront: messageLabel)

            // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

            if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
                view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
                view.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
            }

        } catch {
            // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
            print(error)
            return
        }
```

Comment: might be you to play with `view.layer` i mean you have to add one more sublayer of NavigationBar & bring subview to front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace this:

```
view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
```

With:

`view.layer.insertSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!, below: qrCodeFrameView.layer) //Or below: messageLabel.layer`

Try not to add the sublayer to the top, instead, just insert it below some other subview that's already there, it will ensure the nav bar to show correctly

Comment: Thanks for the quick answering! It work as expected now!! :D